# How to find number of specific strings in a string in c#

Tags: c#, string

There is a string: xxoxoxoxoxoxooxxxxox where x is a seat that is occupied and o is not, I have to find individual occupied seats, with both sides having an x.

I tried to look at

```
for (int i = 0; i < string.Length; i++) { 
    if(string[i]=='x' && string[i + 1]=='o' && string[i + 2] == 'x') 
      { 
        count++; 
      } 
}
```

but i got error so I was wondering if theres a good way to do it.

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: So, given your sample input, what result do you *expect* / need to get back?

Comment: I got index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: Show us where i is coming from.

Comment: You can search a pattern like `oxo` and with using `Regex` you can get all the indexes

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < string.Length; i++)
            {
                if(string[i]=='x' && string[i + 1]=='o' && string[i + 2] == 'x') { count++; }
            }

Comment: This is what I used, but it goes outside of array, im expecting count to be 6, as the string contains that many xox substrings

Comment: your loop runs till the end of the string and then you look 2 chars behind the end. You need to end the loop earlier. Length-2

Comment: So your description is wrong and you're trying to find individual **un**occupied seats?

Comment: Oh yeah your right, I didnt think of that, im not too sharp today. Thank you so much.

Comment: @BotondSzabó are you looking for XXX or XOX?

Comment: Sorry, I typed it wrong, but yeah I meant unoccupied

Comment: @BotondSzabó XXX or XOX or OXO?

Comment: Whatever you're looking for (occupied "0x0" or unoccupied "x0x"), searching for "x0x" will not give you the correct solution: you need `count("x0x") + presence("$0x") + presence("x0%")`, where `$` stands for "beginning of line" and `%` stands for "ending of line".

Comment: Is the one sitting at the end counted as an individual?

Answer (score 1):

As the question is pretty unclear, I am assuming that you are looking for a pattern `xox` and want to know the position of `o`.

you can run a for loop and get the index.

to get the count of such patterns. you can increment the count by 1.

```
string str = "xxoxoxoxoxoxooxxxxox";

for(int i = 0; i < str.Length - 2; i++)
{
    if (str[i] == 'x' && str[i +1] == 'o' && str[i+ 2] == 'x')
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i + 1);
        count++; 
    }
}
```

you can change the character value based on your requirement.

Comment: Good until the seat is near the edge and the sequence is short.

Comment: Complexity is O(n) @Jodrell

Comment: The complexity and memory are good but, doesn't handle edge cases like `"o"`, `"oxx"`, `"xxo"`, `"oxoxo"` etc.

Comment: @Jodrell I don’t think these are valid cases

Comment: I suspect the OP will never tell us but, they are feasible.

Comment: @Jodrell sure I’ll have a look. Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

RegEx approach which gives you all indices of individual occupied seats `oxo` https://dotnetfiddle.net/3jc1Vq

```
string input = "xxoxoxoxoxoxooxxxxox";
//                ^ ^ ^ ^ ^       ^
int[] indices = Regex.Matches(input, "(?<=x)o(?=x)").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Index).ToArray();

// in case you only want the count
int count = Regex.Matches(input, "(?<=x)o(?=x)").Count();
```

Comment: Doesn't work when the `'o'` seat is on the edge.

Comment: @Jodrell op clearly defined the rule _with both sides having an x_ that edge case was not defined / not in scope

Comment: if the answer should be limited to the sequence the OP defined then `return int[] { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 18 };` would be the most efficient and simplest answer.

Comment: .. which actually equals the result of my method

Comment: but in that case, your answer is inferior to my comment. In the general case, your answer will not work in some situations.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [regex.matches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDwMq.png) to find all matches ...

```
        string s = "xxoxoxoxoxoxooxxxxox";
        Regex rx = new Regex("xox");
        foreach (Match match in rx.Matches(s))
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Match index: "+ match.Index);
        }
```

[image]

Comment: No pictures and, what are they the indices of, doesn't look right for either version of the question. What you have there is the first char of the matching regex. Won't for short sequences or when the search is near the edge.

Answer (score 0):

I made [a working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vSl8Ii) that makes use of `ReadOnlySpan<T>` and avoids RegEx and over allocation.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string seats = "xxoxoxoxoxoxooxxxxox";
        var results = seats.ToCharArray().GetSingles('o');
        foreach(var i in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}
                                   
public static class Ext
{
    public static IReadOnlyList<int> GetSingles<T>(this T[] source, T search)
    {
        var results = new List<int>();
        if(source.Length == 0)
        {
            return results;
        }
        
        if (source.Length == 1)
        {
            if (source[0].Equals(search))
            {
                results.Add(0);
            }
            
            return results;
        }
        
        if(source.Length >= 2)
        {
            if (source[0].Equals(search) && ! source[1].Equals(search))
            {
                results.Add(0);
            }
            
            if (source.Length == 2)
            {
                if (!source[0].Equals(search) && source[1].Equals(search))
                {
                    results.Add(1);
                }
                
                return results;
            }
        }
        
        ReadOnlySpan<T> window = new ReadOnlySpan<T>(source, 0, 3);
        int i = 1;
        for(; i < source.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            window = new ReadOnlySpan<T>(source, i - 1, 3);
            if(!window[0].Equals(search) && 
                window[1].Equals(search) &&
               !window[2].Equals(search))
            {
                results.Add(i);
            }
        }
        
        if(!window[1].Equals(search) && window[2].Equals(search))
        {
            results.Add(i + 1);
        }
        
        return results;
    }
}
```

This outputs,

```
2
4
6
8
10
18
```

With the more challenging test data,

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var tests = new string[]
        {
            "",
            "o",
            "x",
            "oo",
            "ox",
            "xo",
            "xx",
            "oxx",
            "oox",
            "xox",
            "xoo",
            "xoxoxoxo",
            "xoxoxoxoo",
            "xoxoxox"
        };
        
        for(var i = 0; i < tests.Length; i++)
        {
            string seats = tests[i];
            Console.WriteLine($"{i}:\"{seats}\"");
            var results = seats.ToCharArray().GetSingles('o');
            foreach(var r in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(r);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[we get the correct output](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6LGixV),

```
0:""
1:"o"
0
2:"x"
3:"oo"
4:"ox"
0
5:"xo"
1
6:"xx"
7:"oxx"
0
8:"oox"
9:"xox"
1
10:"xoo"
11:"xoxoxoxo"
1
3
5
8
12:"xoxoxoxoo"
1
3
5
13:"xoxoxox"
1
3
5
```